# Meaning of marking on LCD CCL power connector?

Tags: connector, identification, wire

What does this marking mean on a cable connector for two wires:

[image]

### Edit

The connection comes from the LM170E03 LCD Screen from Phillips. It is the connectors for the power source for the backlight in the LCD screen.

Comment: Your question has scarce information. Where do those wires come from? Where is the connector usually plugged into?

Comment: @Grebu: Does the Edit help more?

Comment: Seems a JST connector : http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=22 (Well, I know that's not your question...)

Comment: Manufacturer identification marks?

Comment: Why would you want to know given that they probably don't mean anything? How vital is this knowledge for your continued peace of mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See page 23 of the data sheet at:

http://www.beyondinfinite.com/lcd/Library/LG-Philips/LM170E03-TLL1.pdf

Says the marking is a lot number.